# How do I loop a request for user input until the user enters information in Acrobat XI

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I need to program a form field so the user can't proceed to the next field until the field is filled in. I set it up so a message pops up but the user is still allowed to proceed.
Here's what I've got.

var ConstructionType = this.getField("ConstructionType").value;

```
if( ConstructionType == "New Residential" ) 
app.alert("You must enter the Residential Finished Floor Area field before continuing");
else if ( ConstructionType == "Accessory Suite")
    app.alert("You must fill in the Residential Finished Floor Area field before continuing");
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but checkout html5 attribute `required`

Comment: That didn't work but it gave me an inspiration to word my search differently on Google. Thanks

Comment: If you find an answer, answer your own question for others to reference :)

Comment: I didn't find an answer but I figured out how to hide the fields when they weren't needed. Which actually turned out better. Out of sight, out of mind. Although I couldn't use your solution the search brought up the idea of hiding fields not needed.

Comment: I haven't used acrobat before but if it renders HTML there is more than likely an API call to set attributes. Glad you found out your answer!

Comment: It is IMHO a "not good" idea to keep the user in an endless loop within one single field. What would be less restrictive is to have the fields depending on the initial entry either hidden or read-only, and set up the form visually so that it is clear for the user to provide that information.

Comment: @MaxWyss Yes. If the user doesn't know the field is there they won't feel compelled to enter anything

Comment: Here is the code for hiding the fields when I didn't need them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for hiding the fields when I didn't need them.

```
'if(event.value =="New Commercial") {
this.getField("FixNum").display = display.visible;
this.getField("FinArea").display = display.hidden;
} else if(event.value == "Tenant Improvement"){
this.getField("FixNum").display = display.visible;
this.getField("FinArea").display = display.hidden;
} else if (event.value =="Residential Addition") {
this.getField("FinArea").display = display.hidden;
this.getField("FixNum").display = display.hidden;
}`
```